# Android ant problem (for using ProGuard)

Tags: android, ant, proguard

Does anybody know where I can look for an configuration error? I'm getting this error message as soon as I'm trying to compile and to include ProGuard in my project (using the recently released Android SDK). Looking at the mentioned file of the error message it's a file by Google and I don't see any errors there. Any idea? Thx.

```
   ant release
    ...

    BUILD FAILED
    C:\ [...] \Android SDK\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:430: Expecting class path separator ';' before 'SDK\platforms\android-8\android.jar' in argument number 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a CLASSPATH separator character issue.

Change `:` to `;` and see if that helps.

Also, put the path in double-quotes. For example, instead of:

```
Android SDK\platforms\android-8\android.jar:...
```

Use:

```
"Android SDK\platforms\android-8\android.jar";...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the ant "echo" tag to print out the properties and see how they are wrong. To print out all properties set in a build file, use `<echoproperties />` [ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoproperties.html), it is very useful in debugging ant scripts.