# Proguard in eclipse, failing almost before it starts

Tags: android, proguard

This is a real newbie question. I installed proguard, and am trying to export my first app with it. I am getting the following error (real path substituted) in my eclipse console.

[2011-10-13 10:11:56 - RobotInvaders] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2011-10-13 10:11:56 - RobotInvaders] Unable to access jar file "/[workspace path]/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/proguard/lib/proguard.jar"

But I can access it through my xterm. There are no spaces or strange characters in the workspace path. I even changed the permissions with no effect. At first I thought some environment variable might be missing, but the error knows enough to get the whole correct path. The error comes up after about 30 - 45 seconds

Any clues?

Comment: i think, you don't have to install proguard separately. it comes with SDK. why did you installed it separately?

Comment: I copied 4.6 to my proguard folder. previous to that I did an update to the sdk. I just put the proguard.config=proguard.cfg in my default.properties file. to try it out. Did an export and got this error. Poked around looking for what it meant

Answer (score 2):

In C:\android-sdk\tools\proguard\bin\ edit proguard.bat

Delete these three lines

```
IF EXIST "%PROGUARD_HOME%" GOTO home
SET PROGUARD_HOME=..
:home
```

Replace with the path of your sdk tools. My path is..

```
SET PROGUARD_HOME="C:\android-sdk\tools\proguard"
```

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't understand your question but these might help you :

[Using Proguard for Android in Eclipse got Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421262/using-proguard-for-android-in-eclipse-problem)

[Proguard error: Expecting class path seperator - not sure where I need to put a path in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356979/proguard-error-expecting-class-path-seperator-not-sure-where-i-need-to-put-a-p)

[Android ant problem (for using ProGuard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422846/android-ant-problem-for-using-proguard)

Comment: yea, I found these already. There are no spaces in my workspace path.